# What is the ideal way to apply style changes to body tag from Angular2

Tags: angular

So I've got a template I'm trying to adapt to a new NG2 layout. Everything seems to work ok when I have app located within the body. To use angular from the body tag itself, I can use body as the apps selector, but then it wants to duplicate the tag.

My question (since I literally probably wont need any other reason to manipulate body tag from outside of angular... is there a way I can set that up manually... and still ensure theres no real way for state to get out of wack?

eg,

Thanks!

Comment: "To use angular from the body tag itself, I can use body as the apps selector, but then it wants to duplicate the tag." sounds weird. Please share some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881401/style-html-body-from-web-component-angular-2/34892496#34892496 for an example