# how to change class of body in angular2&typescript project

Tags: angular, typescript

I have diffirent classes for login page and other pages in application so after user logged in I need to change class of body element. Here how I am trying to accomplish this..

index.html

```
<body [ngClass]="{
  'dashboard site-navbar-small' :isAuthenticated,
  'login-form login-form-second page-login-second' :!isAuthenticated
}">
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
```

login.component.ts

```
export class LoginComponent {
  @HostBinding('class.login-form.login-form-second.page-login-second')
  siteNavbarSmallClass = false;
  constructor(private auth:Auth){
    this.siteNavbarSmallClass=this.auth.authenticated();
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
 export class AppComponent {
  @HostBinding('class.dashboard.site-navbar-small')
  dashboardClass = false;
  constructor(private auth:Auth){
      this.dashboardClass=this.auth.authenticated();
  }
}
```

I am trying to bind ngClass directive to isAuthenticated field.. but I doesnt affected.  I heard we are not able to change body element via ts, how can I handle it with anyway ?

Comment: Can you share @Component decorator of your components...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bindings outside `<app-root>` are not supported.

What you can do is to use `selector: 'body'` in you `AppComponent` and

```
@HostBinding('class.dashboard')
dashboardClass = false;

@HostBinding('class.site-navbar-small')
siteNavbarSmallClass = false;

...
```

and then set the properties to `true` to get the classes added.

or just

```
document.body.classList.add('dashboard');
```

Comment: Hi, can you eloborate your answer? I edited post regarding to your answer

Comment: how can I add class with have multiple values it throws exceptions when I try this document.body.classList.add('login-form login-form-second');

Comment: `add('login-form', 'login-form-second');` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: @HostBinding('class') siteNavbarSmallClass = 'my-login-class'; works perfect thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use make the `<body>` tag the app element by using `body` as selector and use host-binding to update the app elements classes.

```ts
@Component({
   selector: 'body',
   host:     {'[class.someClass]':'someField'}
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  someField: bool = false;
  // alternatively to the host parameter in `@Component`
  // @HostBinding('class.someClass') someField: bool = false;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    someField = true; // set class `someClass` on `<body>`
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what did you do here? Is this a new component with a selector 'body'? or did you change the AppComponent to be the body?? Please add some additional explanations. I want to make this code valid: `<body [ngClass]="...">` how does you answer make this work?

Comment: @GilEpshtain As it was written 4-years ego, I was learning Angular2. What I remember it that changes the selector to `body` of `AppComponent` and `<body [ngClass]="...">` this will add your class to the `body` element. Thanks for your concern I also wanted that valid code should be their.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to modify the body class.

```
renderer.addClass(document.body, "myClass");
```

or

```
renderer.removeClass(document.body, "myClass");
```