# Best way to add style to body element with angular

Tags: angular

I have this component which does something with dragging. Because of this, I don't want anything on the page to get selected.

Currently I do the following on `mousedown`

```
 document.body.style.userSelect = 'none';
```

and on `mouseup`

```
 document.body.style.userSelect = '';
```

This works, but I'm wondering if angular 4 has a better/neet way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular doesn't provide anything to manipulate the `<body>` element, therefore what you're already doing, is the way to go.

What you can do is, to use `'body'` as selector of your root component and use

```ts
@HostBinding('style.userSelect')
styleUserSelect:String = '';

...

this.styleUserSelect = 'none';
```

You should be aware that this way all content of `<body>` will be purged when Angular is initialized.

See also

- [Style html,body from web component (Angular 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881401/style-html-body-from-web-component-angular-2/34892496#34892496)
- [Angular 2.x bind class on body tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430666/angular-2-x-bind-class-on-body-tag/34430979#34430979)
- [How do I change the body class via a typescript class (angular2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636661/how-do-i-change-the-body-class-via-a-typescript-class-angular2/34637039#34637039)
- [how to change class of body in angular2&typescript project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249161/how-to-change-class-of-body-in-angular2typescript-project/41249296#41249296)