# How can I apply different (full page) backgrounds for some specific URL in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to apply different full page background-color to my login page with "login" as URL. I use `ngAfterViewInit()` and Renderer2 in my login component.  When I visit this page and go back to other pages, all the backgrounds of my pages change like my login page, but I want just my login page background-color change.

**My Login component using Renderer2**

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private router: Router, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background-color', 'yellow');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**My Login component using AfterViewInit**

import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
    import {Router} from '@angular/router';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
this.elementRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = '#E7fff4';
    }
}
```

Comment: there should be an equivalent of ng-class for angular

Comment: Set a bool var to `this.router.url === '/login'` and on a parent element put something like [ngClass]="{'special-background-class': isLoginUrl}` and apply the class.

Comment: there is one problem here , i want full page even we have scroll page must have this background color, so it is just like we set this on body in header tag i can not apply this to my login.component.html file cause it will not work properly full page in height when we scroll page.

Comment: related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881401/style-html-body-from-web-component-angular-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make the following change:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background-color', 'yellow');
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.renderer.removeStyle(document.body, 'background-color');
  // or whatever color you want to change when user move out of login page
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to toggle the body class using AfterViewInit and OnDestroy using a shared function...

```
export class LoginComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  toggleBackgroundClass(): void {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('your-class-name');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.toggleBackgroundClass();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.toggleBackgroundClass();
  }

}
```

When your component loads, it will set the background class and when you navigate away, it will remove the class. Your CSS can be as simple as:

```
body.your-class-name {
  background-color: #E7fff4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the renderer and elementRef

To limit this to a component, add this in the scss

```
:host{
   backgroundColor = '#E7fff4';
}
```